# Calculating area of polygons without script in QGIS Field calculator

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, field-calculator, area

Whenever I click the Field Calculator in the attribute table, I am prompted to created a script in order for it to calculate the area of a polygon. However, I do not want to use code in obtaining a simple area measurement.

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution for this. Any idea how to just obtain a simple area measurement for a polygon (without creating a script)?

Answer (score 11):

There are two tabs under the field calculator - **Expression** and **Function editor**, i  suppose you're referring to the function editor tab which requires coding skills.

If you stay on the **Expression** tab you just have to create a new field and use the following expression :

```
area(geometry)
```

To calculate the area of the current feature.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$area` to calculate the area (ellipsoidal measurement) vs. planimetric measurement of `area ($geometry)`

Comment: The weird thing in the question is that the *default* displayed tab should be the expression tab ... not the other ...